# Can I modify part of locale localeconv() in python

Tags: python, locale

My locale.localeconv() looks like

```
{'int_curr_symbol': 'USD ',
 'currency_symbol': '$',
 'mon_decimal_point': '.',
 'mon_thousands_sep': ',',
 'mon_grouping': [3, 3, 0],
 'positive_sign': '',
 'negative_sign': '-',
 'int_frac_digits': 2,
 'frac_digits': 2,
 'p_cs_precedes': 1,
 'p_sep_by_space': 0,
 'n_cs_precedes': 1,
 'n_sep_by_space': 0,
 'p_sign_posn': 1,
 'n_sign_posn': 1,
 'decimal_point': '.',
 'thousands_sep': ',',
 'grouping': [3, 3, 0]}
```

How do I modify, say, the frac_digits without changing everything else?

Comment: Why not do it via [`locale.setlocale`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale)?

Comment: It sets the whole thing instead of just one attribute

Comment: I've initialized it with `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')`

Answer (score 2):

`locale._override_localeconv` dictionary lets you override items of `localeconv` 's return value.

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, '' )
'English_United States.1252'
>>> locale.currency( 124121 )
'$124121.00'
>>> #change the locale's number of digits after decimal point to zero: 
>>> locale._override_localeconv = {'frac_digits':0} 
>>> locale.currency( 124121 )
'$124121'
```

Comment: give brief and required explanation about your answer.